# How to make an input config file for the function to use?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a function in **rsync.js**

**rsync.js**

```
var onClick = function(){
      exec('rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o\ UserKnownHostsFile = /dev/null" --progress' + src_dir + to_dir,\ 
function(error,stdout,stderr){
console.log('stdout:',stdout)}  )      
}
```

Let suppose I want to run the above code for 3 different directories which are present in the system.So, I need to change only the `src_dir` and `to_dir` to give inputs to the function `onClick`.

In order to do this, I want to make an **input config file** in JSON format, so that I can require that in **rsync.js** and gives only the inputs as `src_dir` and `to_dir` to the function and it works for the 3 of them.

**Question1**: How to iterate the array list in **config.js** file?

**Question2**: How to give the input to the function `onClick`?
For example: `var onClick = function(src_dir= "", to_dir= ""){}`

Try1:
I have made a list of the array for source and destination.
Now I want to iterate it, but unable to do that.

**config.js**

```
module.exports = { 

    src: [
        { src_dir: '/path/to/source/dir/', to_dir : '/path/to/remote/dir'},
             //rest array elements.
        ]
   }
```

Comment: You can first read the list of src and to dir and have it in array. Then iterating using for loop you can run through the list results and have it as you expected.

Comment: yes, this I have understood but unable to implement it.

Comment: @ArunkumarG I have made a list of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var onClick = function(src_dir, to_dir){ // expect 2 paramteres for the onClick function (src,to)
    exec('rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o\ UserKnownHostsFile = /dev/null" --progress' + src_dir + to_dir, function(error,stdout,stderr){
        console.log('stdout:',stdout)
    })      
}

// Load config
var config = require('config.js');

// Iterate through all elements in config.src
for(var i=0;i<config.src.length;i++){
    onClick(config.src[i].src_dir,config.src[i].to_dir)
}
```

Comment: it displays that onClick is not a function.